# iPhone:How to get window frame in UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft or Right?

Tags: iphone

I want to get exactly window frame with x,y,width and height position in `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft`, `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight`, `UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown` and `UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait`.

Please give me any link or any idea to develop this functionality.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're asking to get the window frame hypothetically in advance, or how to get it once the orientation change has actually started to take effect? Also the `UIWindow` doesn't actually rotate — so do you really mean the window or do you just mean the frame of a rotated full-screen view?

Comment: ya change frame of a rotated full screen view any idea???

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a view controller that's being rotated, the new internal rectangle is guaranteed to be correct by the time of `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`. So you can get the new rectangle then from `self.view`. For example:

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:
                       (UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
                       duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    CGRect newInternalRect = self.view.bounds;
}
```

Comment: @Tommay How to manage one view to next view and back to one view with same orientation??? I want to make an app any orientation so any idea??